# Finding the angle of lines detected using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV for a robot vision project - navigating a maze. I can detect the lines where the walls of the maze meet the floor. And now need to use these detected lines to calculate which way the robot should turn.

In order to work out which way the robot should move I believe the solution is to calculate the angle of the walls in relation to the position of the robot. However where both walls are found how do I select which points to use as a reference.

I understand that I can use the python atan2 formula to calculate the angle between two points but after that I am completely lost.

Here is my code:

```
    # https://towardsdatascience.com/finding-driving-lane-line-live-with-opencv-f17c266f15db
# Testing edge detection for maze
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

image = cv2.imread("/Users/BillHarvey/Documents/Electronics_and_Robotics/Robot_Vision_Project/mazeme/maze1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size,kernel_size),0)
low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150

edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)

# create a mask of the edges image using cv2.filpoly()
mask = np.zeros_like(edges)
ignore_mask_color = 255

# define the Region of Interest (ROI) - source code sets as a trapezoid for roads
imshape = image.shape

vertices = np.array([[(0,imshape[0]),(100, 420), (1590, 420),(imshape[1],imshape[0])]], dtype=np.int32)

cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, ignore_mask_color)
masked_edges = cv2.bitwise_and(edges, mask)

# mybasic ROI bounded by a blue rectangle

#ROI = cv2.rectangle(image,(0,420),(1689,839),(0,255,0),3)

# define the Hough Transform parameters
rho = 2 # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi/180 # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 15     # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 40 #minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 30    # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments

# make a blank the same size as the original image to draw on
line_image = np.copy(image)*0 

# run Hough on edge detected image
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(masked_edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),min_line_length, max_line_gap)

for line in lines:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),10)
            angle = math.atan2(x2-x1, y2-y1)
            angle = angle * 180 / 3.14
            print("Angle = ", angle) 

# draw the line on the original image 
lines_edges = cv2.addWeighted(image, 0.8, line_image, 1, 0)
#return lines_edges

#cv2.imshow("original", image)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

#cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("detected", lines_edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite("lanes_detected.jpg", lines_edges)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have added the athn2 forumla in the piece of code that draws blue lines where HoughLinesP has detected lines.

And to convert the results (angle) to degrees I found this formula:

```
angle = angle * 180 / 3.14
```

The following piece of code:

```
print("Angle = ", angle)
```

Prints 13 angles which may or may not equate to the lines in the pic, do they? To avoid getting a - degrees I had to do x2-x1, y2-y1 rather than the other way around which I have seen elsewhere.

I do apologise for my fundental lack of python and mathematical knowledge but any help would be gratefully received.

[image: Lanes Detected]

Comment: Angle relative to what?

Comment: *I believe the solution is to calculate the angle of the walls in relation to the position of the robot* Can you please explain this bit. I am not getting the intuition as to how this would solve your problem.

Comment: @krflol The angle relative to the direction that the robot is pointing.

Comment: @ZdaR Yes the angle of the walls in relation to the position or importantly the direction in which the robot is facing. Once this was known the robot would turn the same number of degrees so that the robot was always facing the same direction as the wall.

Comment: @barny agreed not just yet - i'll stick to my day job :-)

Comment: The angles wouldn't change if the bot moved forward... unless it shifted left or right slightly due to mechanical inefficiencies. I don't think you have a good solution to the problem. I wonder if that floor pattern is unique across the maze..

Comment: @krofl absolutely correct, the angle would stay the same unless the robot veered left or right (that's the point). I have now incorporated Perspective Transform to flatten the image before obtaining the angles of the lines found using HoughLinesP. This is now giving me angles of around 180 degrees. If I invert x and y in this line as follows: angle = math.atan2(x1-x2, y1-y2) I new get angles around 0 degrees to -5 degrees.